# Explanation of the principle of inverted dependency for spring ioc containers

Tags: inversion-of-control, aop

I am a newcomer and have just started using experience Q&A recently. I have some doubts about some questions and hope everyone can help and support me. I hope it is rich and meaningful, dear gods. If there is any unreasonable statement, please include more.

1. What is spring ioc
2. The role and usage rules of ioc
3. The principle of ioc
4. Detailed explanation of ioc's Inversion of control
5. DI Dependency injection of ioc
6. Explanation of IoC's Dependency Inversion Principle
7. Impact of Spring AOP on IOC
8. Problems or errors that need to be noted or avoided during the use process
9. Build IOC in XML format
10. Construct IOC based on annotation form
11. Obtain IOC container beans using class types and automatic injection methods respectively
12. Use deguber to browse the location of the source code IOC, such as beanFactory and context content
13. When obtaining IOC container beans in different ways, occasional errors may occur in the form of implementation classes or interfaces
14. Impact of AOP on IOC containers
15. When the implementation class does not have a method that rewrites the interface, or when the interface and implementation class only have the body and no content, the method rule for pointcut expressions is *. In this case, aop, aop will be used

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.